# UIType Editor throws object reference

Tags: c#, generics, uitypeeditor

I have a .dll file where I have implemented my custom controls and the type editor.

the UITypeEditor works in the .dll file. however when I import the .dll to the main project it give me an object reference error.

My Custom Form and the Type editor is below:

**Form:**

```
public partial class MyBrowseForm<TParentEntity> : Base4Form, IBaseBrowseDialog where TParentEntity : class
{

[Category("Base4Data")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Editor(typeof(BdFormTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]       
    [TypeConverter(typeof(CollectionConverter))]
    public BindingList<MySearchFields> MySearchFieldsCollection
    {
        get => _mySearchFieldsCollection;
        set => _mySearchFieldsCollection = value;
    }

[Browsable(false)]
    public Type MyGenericType => typeof(TParentEntity);
}
```

**UITypeEdior**

```
internal class BdFormTypeEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {

        var svc = provider?.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService))
            as IWindowsFormsEditorService;

        if (context != null)
        {
            var genericType = ((dynamic) context.Instance).MyGenericType;



            var editorFormType = typeof(MyEditorForm<>);

            var editorFormInstance = editorFormType?.MakeGenericType(genericType);
            if (svc != null)
            {
                using (var f = (Form) Activator.CreateInstance(editorFormInstance, null))
                {
                    f.GetType().GetProperty("List")?.SetValue(f, value);
                    if (svc.ShowDialog(f) == DialogResult.OK)
                        return ((dynamic) f).List;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (var f = (Form) Activator.CreateInstance(editorFormInstance, null))
                {
                    f.GetType().GetProperty("List")?.SetValue(f, value);
                    if (svc.ShowDialog(f) == DialogResult.OK)
                        return ((dynamic) f).List;
                }
            }
        }
        return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
    }
}
```

I have created another UITypeEditor and a Form to open from the Typeeditor. (using statement above) 
this time I have added the following code only and I'm not passing values to any property in the form. and I get the same error.

```
var genericType = (Type)context?.Instance.GetPropValue("MyGenericType");

        //var genericArgument = (Type)myGenericTypeProperty.GetValue(context.Instance);
        var editorFormType = typeof(MyEditorForm<>);
        //var genericArguments = new[] { genericArgument };
        var editorFormInstance = editorFormType.MakeGenericType(genericType);

        if (svc != null)
        {
            using (var f = Form)Activator.CreateInstance(editorFormInstance))
```

so this works in the original solution but when I build and import the dll to another solution I get an object reference..

What do you think I'm missing here? any help is appreciated.

Comment: "it give me an object reference error." - *where* does it give that? context please; is there a stack-trace, perhaps? or an example of the calling code? or is it just `PropertyGrid`? or...?

Comment: hypothesis: `((dynamic) context.Instance).MyGenericType;` - any chace `context.Instance` is `null` here? maybe check for that in the `if` immediately above

Comment: It is just a property grid, therefore I have no idea how to catch the exception :(

Comment: if you have all the projects in the solution, just put a break-point in `EditValue`? Alternatively, just put a `try {...} catch(Exception ex) { WriteLog(ex.StackTrace); throw; }` (for any implementation of `WriteLog`) - into `EditValue`

Comment: Hi Marc,  first of all I couldn't catch the exception because the error is given at the design time.

Comment: @MarcGravell I've updated the question accordingly

Comment: You have to tackle this by first learning how to debug exceptions that occur at design-time.  Start here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-debugging-custom-windows-forms-controls-at-design-time